# Semaphores - Consumer Producer example

Tags: synchronization, operating-system, mutex, semaphore

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with the following solution to the Consumer Producer problem:

[image]

I'm assuming there is a chain of events in which something will get messed up but I can't see it. Can anyone clafiry this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that `c += 1` is often implemented by the sequence "load c", "increment c", "store c", then look at different ways `c += 1` and `c -= 1` could be interleaved, because they are not guaranteed to be atomic operations. Here's one such (assume `c = 0` as at the start):

```
Thread 1                  Thread 2
--------                  --------
load c
                          load c
                          decrement
increment
store c
                          store c
```

You would expect that, after executing both `c += 1` and `c -= 1`, that `c` would be back to its original value of `0`, but in this case, it would actually be `-1`, which is a bit of a problem. Thread 1 would expect to see `c == 1`, because it just read `0`, incremented it and stored the resulting `1`; thus the rest of thread 1 might get a little confused.